# Error : MainActivity is not an enclosing class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, click

I create a personnal component view and when we click on this, an other activity starts. There is my manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="fr.freshkamekentrainement.skrt">
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Splash"
        android:theme="@style/Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation"/>
    <activity android:name=".niveaux.LilUziVert_GrowUp"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation"/>
</application></manifest>
```

there is my intent

```
public class Niveauview extends RelativeLayout {
Intent intentNiveau;

//Code

@Override
public void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            intentNiveau = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LilUziVert_GrowUp.class);
            startActivity(intentNiveau);
        }
    });
}}
```

I get error:

> MainActity is not an enclosing class

Notice that `NiveauView` and `MainActivity` isn't in the same package (but they are public). Where does the problem come from? When i try `new Intent(this,LilUziVert_GrowUp.class);` i have an error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only access Foo.this if you're in a inner class of Foo.  Otherwise you need to be passed in an instance of Foo instead.  In the case of a View, every view has an instance of a Context you can get by calling getContext().  So you need to call `intentNiveau = new Intent(getContext(),LilUziVert_GrowUp.class);`

Comment: Thanks, i did it but the method startActivity(intentNiveau) doesnt work

Comment: You also need to call getContext().startActivity(intentNiveau);   And I'd suggest actually learning Java without the distraction of Android, this question just shows you really don't know how to program in it.

Comment: Thanks, im new in Programming, i learned Java first, but as you see i miss some essentials.